# Can other users upload to my account playlist via youtube api?

Tags: api, file-upload, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've only found one thread relating to this and the majority of the comments are saying that it doesn't work, however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687185/youtube-api-upload-to-developers-account) was 2 years ago.

I really want to have a simple form that the user to pick a file from their computer/phone, and upload that to a designated YouTube playlist (not their own).

I guess I'm just looking to see if this is even possible before we promise the client anything.

I've found simple upload demos, however they just upload to the USER that is uploading it, not a public designated playlist.

Comment: I think you cannot directly add a video to a playlist. See this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597780/upload-video-to-specific-playlist-in-youtube) for more information. It may explain why it is uploaded to the USER who login not to the public designated playlist. It maybe also impossible to allow other users to upload video in your account playlist. Hope it cleared up some issues.

Comment: Would also love to know if this is possible.

Comment: In my findings @Lonelydatum, it seems it isn't, but what our idea is that we have our own uploader, which the backend will intercept and push up to our playlist from the backend, basically rules out the 'user' side of the upload process, we have yet to try this though

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Looks like we are trying to do the same thing. What I'm going to do is to upload the video to the user's account and store the video id to a cms. Good luck with your project.